# Return a different datatype from postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the below query in PG

```
SELECT
project.project_id,
project.project_name,
   category.category_name,
   array_agg(row(skill.skill_name,projects_skills.projects_skills_id)) AS skills
  FROM project
    JOIN projects_skills ON project.project_id = projects_skills.project_id
    JOIN skill ON projects_skills.skill_id = skill.skill_id
    JOIN category ON project.category_id = category.category_id
 GROUP BY project.project_name,project.project_id, category.category_name;
```

of particular interest is the below line which seems to return a pseudo-type tuple

```
array_agg(row(skill.skill_name,projects_skills.projects_skills_id)) AS skills
```

I'm unable to create a view of this because of the pseudo type - in addition to this, the row function seems to return a tuple set like the below:

```
skills: '{"(Python,3)","(Node,4)","(Javascript,5)"}' }
```

I could painfully parse it in JavaScript by replacing '(' to '[' etc. but could I do something in postgres to return it preferably as an object?

Comment: Have you tried `json_agg` or `json_object` aggregate functions?

Comment: You forgot to provide your version of Postgres. And "object" is not a valid Postgres data type. What data type do you want to return? `json`? `jsonb`? `text[]`? Or an array of a well-known row type?

Comment: thank you - the version is 9.4 BTW .. ill try out json_agg and TYPE as well. is one way better than the other in anyway? Curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the excellent suggestions to use JSON in the comments, and @Erwin 's to use a registered composite type, you can use a two-dimension array, or a multivalues approach:

Just replace your line

```
array_agg(row(skill.skill_name::text,projects_skills.projects_skills_id::text)) AS skills
```

with the following:

#### Two dimension array option 1

```
array_agg(array[skill.skill_name::text,projects_skills.projects_skills_id::text]) AS skills

-- skills will be '{{Python,3},{Node,4},{Javascript,5}}', thus
-- skills[1][1] = 'Python' and skills[1][2] = '3' -- id is text
```

#### Two dimension array option 2

```
array[array_agg(skill.skill_name),array_agg(projects_skills.projects_skills_id)] AS skills

-- skills will be '{{Python,Node,Javascript},{3,4,5}}', thus
-- skills[1][1] = 'Python' and skills[2][1] = '3' -- id is text
```

#### Multivalues

```
array_agg(skill.skill_name) AS skill_names,
array_agg(projects_skills.projects_skills_id) AS skills_ids

-- skills_names = '{Python,Node,Javascript}' and skill_ids = '{3,4,5}', thus
-- skills_names[1] = 'Python' and skills_ids[1] = 3 -- id is integer
```

Comment: i tried user array[skill.skill_name,projects_skills.projects_skills_id] - but i;m getting **ERROR: ARRAY types character varying and integer cannot be matched**

Comment: @Kunkka this was only intended to illustrate what can be done, however I've updated it with the necessary casts so that it will work now

Comment: stardust - i had to additonally cast the entire array as text too :) **array_agg(array[projects_skills.projects_skills_id::text,skill.skill_name::text]::text) AS skills **

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to register a row type (once):

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (skill_name text, projects_skills_id int);
```

I am guessing `text` and `int` as data types. Use the actual data types of the underlying tables.

```
SELECT p.project_id, p.project_name, c.category_name
     , array_agg((s.skill_name, ps.projects_skills_id)::my_type) AS skills
FROM   project          p
JOIN   projects_skills ps ON p.project_id = ps.project_id
JOIN   skill            s ON ps.skill_id = s.skill_id
JOIN   category         c ON p.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP  BY p.project_id, p.project_name, c.category_name;
```

There are many other options, depending on your version of Postgres and what you need exactly.